# Docker Desktop Failed to Start

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I am trying to start docker desktop after installing it on my remote windows vm
machine, the installation went well but it is unable to start. I am following https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install document and all prerequisits are statisfied.  The error i get is as follows:

```
Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException:
Unhandled exception: job failed with message: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 9460B783-234A-432D-8ED3-FCCB75C89EBA)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID 9460B783-234A-432D-8ED3-FCCB75C89EBA).
   at Docker.Core.Logging.ClientExceptionInterceptor.<InterceptResponseAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\ClientExceptionInterceptor.cs:line 17
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.Core.Logging.LoggingMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\LoggingMessageHandler.cs:line 37
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.HttpClientExtensions.<PostJsonWithJsonResponseAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\HttpClientExtensions.cs:line 22
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.BackendAPI.BackendAPIClient.<StartHyperVVMAsync>d__11.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\BackendAPI\BackendAPIClient.cs:line 102
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.LinuxHyperVEngine.<DoStartAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\LinuxHyperVEngine.cs:line 60
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.<StartAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:line 72
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.Engines.<RestartAsync>d__29.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\Engines.cs:line 274
Original stacktrace:
   at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.HandleUpdatedJob(CIMConcreteJob updatedJob) in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 800
   at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.<HandleMaybeAsyncJob>d__37.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 740
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.<StartVMAsync>d__29.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 588
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Backend.HyperV.<StartAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperV.cs:line 102
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Backend.HttpAPI.HyperVAPIController.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HttpAPI\HyperVAPIController.cs:line 44
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```

Comment: the Docker client or the Docker CE is nothing more than an application that makes requests to a backend that runs at port 2376 on windows. Make sure this port is available. Also make sure you don't have a firewall or antivirus blocking Docker.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a `virtual machine` running on the machine where you have `docker` installed. You should pause the virtual machine and then restart docker.

Comment: There are additional hints in the stack trace about missing or non-running components. It might make sense to include those in your answer as well.